# Send email using c# to a Gmail account - html formatting issues

Tags: c#, gmail

I've built a small client applicatoin in c#.
I am sending the emails via gmail.
When I format my html and add underlines, using the following format:

```
<span style="text-decoration:underline"> hello </span>
```

Gmails ignore my underlining. Is there any workaround?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

email clients are notoriously bad at standards compliance,

Try the `<u></u>` tag around your text and see how that works for you.

There is actually a [group trying to establish some standards in html for email clients](http://www.email-standards.org/).
They also have a list of recommendations on what issues exist in certain email clients, [for instance gmail](http://www.email-standards.org/clients/gmail/).